# Gmail web says "not sent to spam", downloaded version doesn't

Tags: gmail

The web version of Gmail sometimes tells me a message wasn't sent to
spam because of my filter settings:

[image: I later realized I probably don't need this image, but since I xwd'd it, I'm going to use gosh darn it!]

However, after I download that message via IMAP and look at the
headers, I see no such indication ("show original" also shows no such
indication).

Is this information lost if I don't view the message on the web?

Can I make gmail add a "X-GMAIL-FILTERED: Spam to Inbox" or something
header?

Comment: What do you mean the by the downloaded version of Gmail? Do you mean Thunderbird or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a GMail web feature and would not be included in the normal HTML of an email. The information is not really lost, but more a less not an included feature of using IMAP or POP access.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought. If I delete the message permanently from the web interface, the information really is lost? Since my only copy (the IMAP copy) won't have it?

Comment: If you downloaded the message on a client it will stay there.

Comment: Right, but the fact that gmail originally labelled it spam and then moved it to inbox due to a filter is lost forever (unless gmail has filter logs, which I don't think it does)

Comment: Well you could choose an option to also apply a label or something to the messages you chose to never send to spam. Then you could identify messages that were suppose to go to spam. But no, if you're using some client, you will never know otherwise.

Comment: OK, I tried this. The label shows up in webmail, but not in the IMAP-downloaded version of the email. I was hoping for an "X-Label:" header, but no such luck.

Comment: I'm really not sure what email client you are using, but I know one such as Thunderbird supports the ability to sync the labels that Gmail has, with Thunderbird. I have not really had a chance to delve into how Gmail handles labels and such via IMAP though.

Comment: Wow. I use getmail myself. I'm guessing this is a special Thunderbird feature, not part of the IMAP spec (as you note).

Comment: According to this page here (https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail) Thunderbird also uses IMAP access to accomplish this, so I don't believe it is different.

Comment: OK, I've actually done this by pulling "[Gmail]/Spam" in my getmail rc file. However, I dislike pulling to multiple folders, especially when all my labelled messages are also in INBOX.

Comment: Well, sorry but there is not much else to do. Gmail's labels are treated like folders rather than tags I guess, so the suggestion I made in the comments earlier may be useless. Other then that suggested way that is all I can think of.

Comment: No, no. Your suggestion was good, thank you. I just meant that this is getting to be too much work (for me <G>) for something that I thought was simple.